# how to receive text sms to specific port..

Tags: android

How to receive text sms to a specific port? I have been looking for an answer to this question but to no avail. This has been asked a few times but nobody seems to have a clear answer. My code is as follows:

--MANIFEST FILE--

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSRecieve" android:enabled="true"> 
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
<data android:scheme="sms" /> 
<data android:host="localhost" /> 
<data android:port="15005" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

--SMS sending method--

```
String messageText = msgTxt.getText().toString(); 
short SMS_PORT = 15005; 
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
smsManager.sendDataMessage("5556", null, SMS_PORT, messageText.getBytes(), null, null);
```

--Broadcast Receiver code--

```
static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"; 
//static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";(tried this too, but failed) 

if (intent.getAction().equals(SMSNotifyExample.ACTION)) { 
...do some work.. 
}
```

I also tried to replace `android:name` to `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` but the result is the same.

My application does not receive the SMS on the specified port. Once I remove the following line it works fine:

```
<data android:scheme="sms" /> 
<data android:host="localhost" /> 
<data android:port="15005" />
```

Could you suggest what am I missing?

Comment: There's a bounty for this question. I really need this answered too, so I'm hoping somebody sees it and has an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hint!

I use this and it works:

```
        <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="10">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:port="50009" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

[**NOTE:** The code that i have mentioned below is not working on the emulator but successfully on my LG P350 having Android V2.3]

I have used the demo code given on [mobiForge](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) but have changed the **sendTextMessage()** to **sendDataMessage()** with PORT_NO as 8901 (also converted text data to byte[] data).
My receiver is:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
            <data android:scheme="sms" /> 
            <data android:port="8901" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

A working example is [KRVarma's SMSDemo](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/SMSDemo?r=37) which is also functional.