# Android receive Data_Sms

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

My android app sends a Data sms. All the phones are able to receive that message except my android.
I have added a broadcast receiver in the manifest:

`<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="10">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:port="5009" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>`

The application does not give any response when data sms is received, although the msg reaches the inbox. Help.

Comment: have you tried`code`<data android:scheme="sms" host="*" android:port="5009" />`code`If a host is not specified for the filter, the port attribute and all the path attributes are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be a known issue, see this Stackoverflow question:
[How to send and receive data SMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757229/android-how-to-send-and-receive-data-sms-messages)

[This blog](http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/sending-and-receiving-sms-in-android) seemed to suggest it is possible, but the comments underneath indicate somebody never got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving a Binary DATA SMS is currently disallowed/broken in the Android O Preview 2. See this:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62052486