# How I can send message in android without show message in the SMS Inbox?

Tags: android

Im can send sms with this code :

```
 SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage("5556", null, "Hi Havij", null, null);
```

But I dont like my message go in Inbox ! I want dont show it Nowhere ...

Comment: If the messages are being written to the Provider without your app having explicitly done so, then you're running on KitKat or above. In that case, your app will need to be the default SMS app to prevent those writes. Any non-default app using the SmsManager methods to send will have its messages written automatically. The default is responsible for writing its own, and can choose not to do so. However, writing a full-blown SMS app is not trivial.

Comment: my app is not a sms sender application ! I want send some data to my server ... However How I can delete my message after sent it ? such as sms blocker apps ?

Comment: Currently, the only way I know to send SMS as non-default without it showing in the Provider is to send data SMS. I have seen one app that somehow deletes messages immediately after they're written without being the default, but I've not yet found out their method.

Comment: thanks ! can u give a sample or link for this ?

Comment: If you mean an example of data SMS, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757229/how-to-send-and-receive-data-sms-messages) should help you.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution might be deleting that SMS, But according to [Google Docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-sms-provider) after 4.4 no app can delete messages except the default messaging app:

> Also, the system now allows only the default app to write message data to the provider, although other apps can read at any time. Apps that are not the user's default can still send messages

and for more info I suggest u see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614211/deleting-android-sms-programatically).

**UPDATE**

after a little search I found what you need but as I told you before it seems its impossible in android 4.4 but if you want to do such work with lower versions of android please take a look at 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically?lq=1)

Comment: after a little search i found what you need. I updated my answer @user3787191

Comment: Im need do in all version ! my code work on all version under 4.4 But in 4.4 my message save in defaul app !

Comment: not sure but try removing uses-sdk part in ur manifest file. it might works.

Comment: just see a comment from one of the most famous android programmers that repeated my answer.
Please take a look at this post specially CommonsWare's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000013/send-and-receive-request-via-sms-instead-of-http

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is you may send data SMS.

```
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();   
 byte[] messageInBytes = stringMessage.getBytes();  
 smsManager.sendDataMessage(Mobile_no, null, SMS_PORT, messageInBytes , null, null);
```