# send and receive request via sms instead of http

Tags: android, multithreading, network-programming

in my android application I want to send requests to server via sms if there was no internet connection or network.
I am changing the Volley library code. http request is synchronous, when you send the request, thread waits until the response or error get received from server, but when you send sms, thread continue to work and doesn't wait to get the response sms so I am forced to use Callback functions(listeners).
is there any better approach. is it good idea to use `wait` and `notify` to make sms connection synchronous?

Comment: "is there any better approach" -- do not change the Volley library code. Instead, design your own library that can handle completely asynchronous responses via completely separate operations. Note that your SMS approach is unlikely to be successful on Android 4.4 and above, unless the SMS messages that you receive in response will be valued by the user. All SMS messages on Android 4.4+ go to the user's SMS inbox; there is no means of you intercepting and consuming SMS messages.

Comment: Hi, I have a question. If i sign my app in Google, Then can i receive SMS without valued by the user?