# SMS as a data link

Tags: android, sms

How could I send an SMS from one app to another (on a different phone), hiding* it from other apps ?

*: because its content would be irrelevant for other apps or the user

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Hope my edits will help.

Comment: Ah. Easy answer: [data sms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757229/how-to-send-and-receive-data-sms-messages). These aren't handled by the Provider, so they won't show in any other SMS app, including the native app. Though, the recipient would need to have an app on their device with the appropriate Receiver.

Comment: But don't data sms require a data link (Edge, 3G, 4G) ? Can they be as fast as SMS ?

Comment: "But don't data sms require a data link (Edge, 3G, 4G) ?" - No. "Can they be as fast as SMS ?" - Yes.

Comment: Are you sure that data sms are not sent through data link ? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9108/what-is-a-data-sms

Comment: "Are you sure that data sms are not sent through data link ?" - Yep. FWIW, it's an easy test. Just send yourself a data SMS with your mobile data connection turned off.

Comment: You are right, it works :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Mike M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) for the answer:

Using data SMS is the solution. They are sent just like normal SMS, but are not broadcasted. An excellent tutorial can be found here: http://codetheory.in/android-sms/