# Is it possible to read what is sent in sms in android app and use the data and then delete the sms so only the app sees it?

Tags: android, sms, gsm

I have a question... I wonder, is it possible to make an application, that will read specific sms (always the same value, 2 numbers), and then delete the sms, so that the user does not see it (meaning that only the app will see it and use the data, but the user of the app will not be bothered with the information the app used)? The application would first send sms to the other device and then it would get the response in two float numbers. Is there a possibility to make that?

Comment: In any version of Android since KitKat (API >=19) , your app would have to be the default SMS app to be able to accomplish that. What are you trying to do, exactly? There might be other options.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm trying to send x and y coordinates from my gps module, and then my device will send me x and y via sms to my phone. I need to read that x and y coordinates in my Android app, so I can pint point it on google maps. I don't have internet connection, only gsm module...

Comment: Is it your app on both devices?

Comment: @MikeM. no... one device uses Arduino gps module and Arduino GSM module to send text msg, to Android device, that will receive coordinates from arduino gps, so that android can pin point here arduino is located...

Comment: Well, I'm not at all familiar with Arduino, but if you can configure it to send data SMS to a specific port, instead of regular text messages, then those messages won't appear in the SMS database on the receiving device. Which version of Android is the receiving device running?

Comment: @MikeM. kit kat and above... How do you mean if I can send SMS to a specific port? ... I don't have internet connection at all on arduino...

Comment: You don't need an internet connection. It's handled over the GSM network. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757229/how-to-send-and-receive-data-sms-messages) describes how you'd handle the receipt in Android, but I've no clue what you'd need to implement the Arduino side of it.