# sending notifications from one app user to the other

Tags: android

i am creating a panic button android app for my project,when you click the button it sends a message with your current location passed inside via SMS,now i want that message with the location to come in as a notification to other users of the app,is it possible to do that without me having a server.FYI the user inserts the phone numbers of the next of kin when they first use it.

Comment: Given that the user will be entering the recipients' numbers themselves, then yes, this is possible.

Comment: if its possible how do i do it?

Comment: how do i send push notifications by pressing a button to other users of the app without setting up a server

Comment: If you want to do this over SMS, I would recommend using data SMS, so that only your app receives the incoming messages. An example can be found in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9853822). You would probably want to use a different port than 8901, though, as I know of at least one provider that uses that port for voice mail data updates.

Comment: the app is already sending sms's, what i want the app to do is send notifications to other users of the same app.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Send your message over data SMS so it doesn't show as a regular text message, and when your app on the other end receives it, it can issue the appropriate notification. Since the message won't be visible to other SMS apps, it'll be just like a push notification.