# Cordova plugin for send and receive data sms

Tags: cordova, sms, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am going to use `cordova` to send and receive data SMS.

Does anybody know about a plugin for that or how can I open ports in `cordava`?.

How do I start?

Thanks

Comment: You should really start with a google search. Having said that, Twilio is a popular SMS service, I use it on my app to only send texts. There are [plugins for it already](https://github.com/twilio/cordova-plugin-twilio-chat), but you will need an account and have to pay $$.

Comment: I think Twilio is a sms server.
But i want user send sms with his simcart but the sms not slowing in inbox .
You can see more info here (implement in native android): 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757229/how-to-send-and-receive-data-sms-messages

Thanks