# Working example of sendDataMessage() for android

Tags: android, sms

I have tried to use the **sendDataMessage()** of **android.telephony.SmsManager** with the help of almost every sample that i could come accross.. Yet no success..

[In case u want to see the code then simply check the "Sending Sms android" link on mobiForge, i guess its the most popular one (and the one that i've used).]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726976/how-to-recieve-text-sms-to-specific-port) is one of the examples in reference to this question.

When i use the standard receiver shown in samples as follows, my Broadcast Receiver does indeed get activated and i am able to see the Toast which contains my message thus proving that my receiver is successfully running. [By the way, i am calling the **SmsManager.sendTextMessage()** which is working successfully so no issues there].

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

However when i use the following receiver, i am unable to get the Toast which means that my receiver is clearly **not** getting activated, hence no Toast.

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
                <data android:port="8901"/>
                <data android:scheme="sms"/>
            </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

My question here is **Why?**
In case some of you are thinking that the port number in my sendDataMessage() is not right then i assure you that its 8901 which is a **short** value.

Hence i would like to request anyone with a solution to this to either explain the solution or provide a working example.

Thanking anyone who can help in advance!

Best Regards,
Siddhant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i seem to have found out the problem in my code.

The fix was to change the **android:name** value in the above shown receiver from **android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED** to **android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED**

So the new receiver will look like:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />  
                <data android:port="8901"/> 
                <data android:scheme="sms"/> 
            </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Thanks to [KRVarma SMSDemo](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/SMSDemo?r=37) which provided some really useful insight after understanding the code.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1576) are details of a possible bug with the Android emulator regarding this functionality.

Comment: Actually i even used the apk on my Samsung Galaxy S phone and i have the same problem.

Comment: Btw thanx [aldridmc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/754048/aldridmc) for helping. :-)