# receive sms sent to a particular port

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, intentfilter

It is a recurrent question but I wasn't able to find a complete enough documentation on this topic.

I already have a working application able to intercept SMS, when it is send with default parameter with kannel or other device. My manifest look like this :

```
<receiver
    android:name=".sms.SMSListener"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />    
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It works both with `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` and `android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED`.

But for the purpose of my application, the SMS must not appear in the user-inbox. For that, kannel sent the SMS to a specific port. It is already working on Blackberry, so I guess the sending part of the problem is already working. 
Also it may be possible to achieve this goal via other means, I need to implement this solution in order to stay coherent with other similar project. Another reason for that, is to avoid my `BroadcastReceiver` to be fired at each received SMS (and thus needing to parse each received SMS).

However with my current manifest, I don't receive SMS sent to a specific port (my receiver isn't fired at all). After some research, I found those topic [how to receive text sms to specific port..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726976/how-to-receive-text-sms-to-specific-port), [How to send and receive data SMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757229/android-how-to-send-and-receive-data-sms-messages). 
Someone say that adding :

```
<data android:scheme="sms" />
<data android:port="1234" />
```

is enough to work (unfortunately, it doesn't works for me). However according to the documentation ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html ) you need to specify the `android:scheme` then the `android:host` in order for `android:port` to be taken into account. As far as I understand the documentation, you could just specify `android:scheme` and the intent-filter should still be functionnal.
However as soon as I specify the `android:scheme`, my `BroadcastReceiver` cease to work, whether or not I send the sms with a specific port :

```
<receiver
    android:name=".sms.SMSListener"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />    
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So my questions are the following:

1. is there somewhere a documention about which value `android:scheme` can take ?
2. which value should I use for `android:host` ?
3. is there somewhere an app which listen SMS to every port so I can be sure that the test SMS is correctly sent (just to double check this part) ?

Comment: if you want port addressed messages then you need to use android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED and not android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED. One of the links you mentioned has the right way to use it too

Comment: Yes that's right but it doesn't work either with DATA_SMS_RECEIVED...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally manage to understand what was wrong :

I was sending my data sms to the port 2948 which is reserved for WAP-PUSH message.
So android do not broadcast those message to my android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED receiver. Using a different port solved the issue.

Moreover, android seems to have problems with 8 bits encoded SMS (at least it rise a warning in the logs.). However my main problem is solved.